# Django Form Validators on Comparing One Object Against Another

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a Non Disclosure Agreement form that a user fills out after registering and logging in.  I am using a custom signup form with AllAuth and pre-populating parts of the form.  I pre-populate the first and last name into the top part of the form as shown below in first screen shot, but as a part of the digital signature I am setting up; I need to validate the typed signature field matches the name of the `first_name` and the `last_name` concatenated together per the second screen-shot. I know I need to setup a validator based on [Django Form & Field Validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/) and I've tried several things but just can't get my mind rapped around it.  Any help putting this together would be huge...thank you.
[image]

[image]
**My Models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile", verbose_name="user")
    ...

class NonDisclosure(Timestamp):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="nda", verbose_name="profile")
    user_signature = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Signature')
    user_street = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Street Address')
    user_city = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='City')
    user_state = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name='State Initials')
    user_zip = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Zip Code')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    cash_on_hand = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Cash on Hand')
    value_of_securities = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Value of Securities')
    equity_in_real_estate = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Equity on Real Estate')
    other = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Other Assets')

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.profile.username

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self.profile.first_name

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self.profile.last_name

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.profile.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Non Disclosure Agreement'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Non Disclosure Agreements'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.profile

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nda_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**My Views:**

```
class NonDisclosureForm(BaseModelForm):
    cash_on_hand = forms.CharField(required=False)
    value_of_securities = forms.CharField(required=False)
    equity_in_real_estate = forms.CharField(required=False)
    other = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NonDisclosure
        fields = ['user_signature', 'user_street', 'user_city', 'user_state', 'user_zip', 'phone', 'cash_on_hand', 'value_of_securities', 'equity_in_real_estate', 'other']

class NdaCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = NonDisclosureForm
    template_name = 'nda/nda_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(NdaCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should subclass `ModelForm`, not `BaseModelForm`. Write a [`clean_<fieldname>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method for your `user_signature` field, and make sure that the value is as expected. You can access `self.instance.created_by` to check.

```
class NonDisclosureForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = NonDisclosure
        fields = ['user_signature', ...]

    def clean_user_signature(self):
        user_signature = self.cleaned_data['user_signature']
        expected_name = '%s %s' % (self.instance.created_by.first_name, self.instance.created_by.last_name)
        if user_signature != expected_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Signature does not match')
        return user_signature
```

Then you need to update your view so that it sets `instance.created_by`. You can do this by overriding `get_form_kwargs`.

```
class NdaCreate(CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NdaCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = NonDisclosure(created_by=self.request.user)
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time...this certainly makes sense...mostly :)  I am getting a `'created_by' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
` error in the browser.  I am assuming - correct me if I'm wrong, that the `created_by` in my `CreateView` is simply there because its in my `ModelForm` clean definition and not an actual model object.  Any clue to the error?

Comment: You have `instance.created_by` in your question, so I assumed your model had a foreign key to `User`. If that's not the case, you'll have to adjust the code slightly.

Comment: You know, that is my fault...I've been toying with this for so long, I can't remember why I set it that way and since the form worked(aside from signature validation) I wasn't aware of an issue.  Either way, I changed `created_by` to `user` and changed `get_form_kwargs` to `kwargs['instance'] = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)` and it validates brilliantly!!  Now the only thing is, it doesn't actually save the form on `submit` - no errors, just doesn't save.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to set the instance to a `Profile` instance. You are creating a `NonDisclosure`, so instance should be a `NonDisclosure`.

Comment: I get a `'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` when using `NonDisclosure`, which is the same error I get if I used the `created_by`...I am not wise enough to defend my position on making it a 'profile' instance, I based my `profile` structure off http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/model-creation-onetoone-relationship-signals-django-admin#profile-model - with that said, is there anything you can recommend that would take this the rest of the way?  The way it is now as a Profile instance it validates, just doesn't actually create the form.  Thank you.

Comment: The instance type must match the form's model, it's got nothing to do with being wise. Please show your `NonDisclosure` model.

Comment: You can set the instance's `profile`, i.e. `instance=NonDisclosure(profile=...)`. You'll then need to update the form to use `self.instance.profile.user`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109585/discussion-between-studio-rooster-and-alasdair).

Comment: Thank you.  I actually got your solution working on validating the names after I crawled backwards through my code and finding other errors.